# Joplin's Peacherine Rag, piano fingering in bar 16

Tags: piano, fingering

I attach bars 15-16 of Scott Joplin's 'Peacherine Rag' for piano (in 2/4 time). Perhaps I'm overlooking something obvious, but how is one supposed to play bar 16 - I refer to the super-stretch apparently needed for the voices in the right hand?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the damper pedal at the beginning of the measure and release it as you play beat 2. If you prefer, you can release it on the `&` of 1. It's not necessary to fully sustain the right-hand chord.